# iPhone App- Getting rid of a page curl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, modalviewcontroller, page-curl

In the navigation section of a program, I added a "favorites" section so the user can save his/her favorite pages to go to, and then the program will load it directly.  The "favorites" view is loaded using a UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl animation, making the page curl.  When a button to load a favorited page is pressed, a view with a UIWebview is called and the page loads.

The problem is, I can't get the page curl to disappear.  If I use [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO]; then I can not have the Webview load, because the view controller no longer has control.  How can I load the Webview and get rid of the page curl at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not appear this is possible.  Based on Apple's Modal View documentation, you can not switch to another view during a page curl, or it will permanently remain. You must dismiss the page curl.